# Which ubuntu for win 8?

Tags: dual-boot

I really want ubuntu 12.04 for the LTS but am I able to dual boot it on windows 8? I have already tried 12.04 and a few others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the 64 bit point releasess 12.04.2 and 12.04.3 will install on a Windows 8 machine.  There are still issues to fix, but boot-repair does a pretty good with them.